# group_concat() do MySql no SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, query, group-concat

Criei uma tabela para exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte conteúdo:

```
select * 
from table_t;
```

[image]

E preciso obter o seguinte resultado:
[image]
No MySql utilizo a seguinte query:

```
select group_concat(concat_ws(' - ',id,descri)) id_descri, tipo 
from table_t
group by tipo;
```

E no SqlServer? Obrigado!

Comment: Por acaso, não seria possível fazer na aplicação isso? Por exemplo, seleciona os tipos, dai faria um loop no resultado e para cada tipo seleciona as descrições e ids! Eu fazia dessa forma com group_concat, mas já tive problemas de lentidão com uma tabela muito grande e manutenção também era mais complicado.

Comment: Sim, seria possível, como conheço o recurso no MySql e por questão de desempenho prefiro que seja no próprio db.

Comment: Entendi, mas quanto a questão de desempenho, quando fiz isso e tive uma grande quantidade de linhas, a performance foi muito maior na própria aplicação, mas dai você deve saber então quanto ao seu lado ai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tipo, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, tipo) + ' - ' + descri
                    FROM table_t iT
                    WHERE iT.tipo = T.tipo
                    ORDER BY tipo
                    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS id_descri
FROM table_t T
GROUP BY tipo
```

ou mais conciso

```
SELECT tipo, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, tipo) + ' - ' + descri
                    FROM table_t iT
                    WHERE iT.tipo = T.tipo
                    ORDER BY tipo
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS id_descri
FROM table_t T
GROUP BY tipo
```

Comment: Fiquei curioso nessa resposta porque queria uma função estilo o `group_concat()`no Sql-Server. Poderia explicar sua resposta @Bruno?

Comment: Isso, essa foi a solução. Aqui temos uma versão mais antiga que o SQL Server 2017, e ai o STRING_AGG não tá disponível, só o FOR XML PATH.

Answer (score 7):

Apenas para complementar a resposta para futuras pesquisas (*como eu precisei*), a partir da versão 2017 do SqlServer foi implementada a função `STRING_AGG()`, que tem a mesma característica do `group_concat`.

Na sua query ficaria assim:

```sql
select STRING_AGG(CONCAT(id, ' - ', descri), ',') id_descri, tipo 
from table_t 
group by tipo;
```

ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017