# Agrupar dados de uma Query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, group-by, group-concat

Eu faço um GROUP BY em um resultado de uma query e o resultado vem dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber se é possivel trazer agrupado desta forma?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber se esse agrupamento é melhor fazer no PHP ou na Query e como pode ser feito?

Segue meu código:

**Query SQL**

```
SELECT id,cliente, descricao, forma_pgto, bandeira, valor, codigo, data, cod_aut
FROM ItensVendidos
WHERE data BETWEEN '2017-05-22' AND '2017-05-22'
GROUP BY id,cliente, descricao, forma_pgto, bandeira, valor, codigo, data, cod_aut
```

Comment: Uma function para a descrição, ou uma subconsulta resolveria seu problema.[veja](http://www.devmedia.com.br/construindo-funcoes-para-sql-server/20934)

Comment: Vou remover o código PHP da sua pergunta para torná-la mais clara, tudo bem?

Comment: Ok @Marconi sem problemas!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), agrupando por `COD_AUT`, se este for o único parâmetro em comum.

Logo:

```
SELECT id, 
       cliente, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(descricao) as descricao, 
       forma_pgto, 
       bandeira, 
       valor, 
       codigo, 
       data, 
       cod_aut 
FROM   itensvendidos 
WHERE  data BETWEEN '2017-05-22' AND '2017-05-22' 
GROUP  BY cod_aut
```

---

Isto irá retornar como "*VENDAS 1,VENDAS 2,VENDAS 3,VENDAS 4*", se quiser mostra-los sem virgula poderá utilizar o `SEPARATOR` do MySQL ([documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)) e escolher o separador que preferir. Também poderá tratar isto no PHP usando `str_replace`/`strtr` ou usar `explode` para criar uma array.

Comment: O `Grup_Contat` Funciona no Sql-Server @Inkeliz?

Comment: Eu vi a tag `mysql`, por isso respondi, agora não sei se possui ou não, talvez tenha algum recurso equivalente.

Comment: Agora que reparei também, ele colocou Tag `Mysql` e `Sql-Server`.

Comment: Achei uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60234/group-concat-do-mysql-no-sqlserver) aqui

Comment: Me desculpa foi sem querer que coloquei Mysql é no sql server. Acabei de tentar e o Group_CONCAT não funciona no SQL Server

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/string_agg-function-in-sql/